# Pre-render images

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a div called `#highlights` which swaps article titles and illustrations. When I change to a new illustration using jQuery like this

```
$("#highlights").css("background","url("+path+")");
```

the background picture being set shows up slowly for the first time. How could I fix this?

Comment: You can get images into the cache by loading them into an image object first.

Comment: Have you looked into the use of Sprites?

Comment: Prerendering is something completely different from preloading. I myself am looking for a non-hacky way to prerender large images *that I have already preloaded*, but that make the browser lag when I try to display them. OP might have been after a way to preload images, but the title suggests otherwise. Not a dupe

Answer (score 8):

You probably want to [preload the images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476679/preloading-images-with-jquery) (courtesy of [James](https://stackoverflow.com/users/21677/james)):

```
function preload(arrayOfImages) {
    $(arrayOfImages).each(function(){
        $('<img/>')[0].src = this;
        // Alternatively you could use:
        // (new Image()).src = this;
    });
}

// Usage:

preload([
    'img/imageName.jpg',
    'img/anotherOne.jpg',
    'img/blahblahblah.jpg'
]);
```

Comment: -1 If you knew it is a dupe, why didn't you flag it?